# Output custom event metric in php

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to display metrics from Google Analytics on a website. Standard metrics are no problem, but I cannot find a way to access custom event actions. It could be that I'm simply not using the right terms. I'm using Analytics Reporting API v4.

```
function getReport($analytics, $value) {

  $VIEW_ID = "138852421";

  // Create the DateRange object.
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
  $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

  // Create the Metrics object.
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
  $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

  $pageviews = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $pageviews->setExpression("ga:pageviews");
  $pageviews->setAlias("pageviews");

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions, $pageviews));

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}
```

I tried to add an image, but it seems I need more rep.
When I try to add a custom action the same way as a normal metric the whole page will not load.

Comment: What do you mean by custom action? Are talking about Event Category, Event Action?

Comment: Event Action, I see why it was not very clear in my post. apologies.

Comment: So you are you getting a 400 or a 200 response from the API. Are you using [`ga:eventAction` dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=event_tracking&jump=ga_eventaction)